# Delete items from array and later get back them in new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
$hackers = array ('Alan Kay', 'Peter Norvig', 'Linus Trovalds', 'Larry Page');
```

I want to delete 1st two items and later want to get back just deleted items in an array

Comment: Did you try or search anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php). It returns an array of the elements that it removed:

```
$first_two = array_splice($hackers, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your kind help